# techniques for sampling graphs? (possibly implemented in r packages)

Tags: r, sampling, graph-theory, igraph

Let's say I have a very large graph that proves impractical for visualization ends and I wanted to sample a random subgraph.

(I know that I can filter out a subgraph via measures like degree, components, weights... but this is not my point)

Is there any procedure that I can use to get a random sample from the graph?
I see that the `igraph` package has two sampling functions that  seem however to be generic and not specifically designed for  sampling graphs. But if they are in that package there must be a reason!

(Is it as easy as random sampling edges i.e. rows?)

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no one way to sample a graph because the idea of sampling a graph isn't well-defined. Do you sample nodes and let edges "fall off"? Do you sample edges and leave isolated nodes? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is exactly the point of my question: I wondered if the idea of sampling from a graph has been defined by anyone. The aim would be to preserve "the most" of the original graph - this could be defined as keeping some measures invariant, as in a geometric transformation. (A graph is a topological object if I am not wrong.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a large number of research on *graph sampling* (easily discoverable by simple Internet search, by the way). The following is just a **small representative sample** of this *research stream*:

- http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5865 (nice overview, I would read this first)
- http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0010012
- http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1150479
- http://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/sampling-kdd06.pdf
- http://www.deutsche-telekom-laboratories.de/~panhui/publications/graph_sampling_simplex11.pdf
- http://charuaggarwal.net/selectives.pdf
- http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/~crshalizi/notabene/graph-sampling.html
- http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/cross_fac/complexity/people/staff/delgenio/gsampler
- http://systemg.research.ibm.com/analytics-sampling.html (seems to be commercial)
- http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5961350
- http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10651-011-0170-3

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr. I do not see any method that has been implemented in a r package, isn't it?

Comment: @DarioLacan: You're welcome. Yes, to the best of my knowledge and based on extensive search, currently there are no R packages, implementing graph sampling of any type. Thank you for accepting, feel free to upvote as well, if you like my answer. I will update it and let you know, if I will run across new or relevant information.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: Have you since found any R packages for graph sampling?

Comment: @histelheim: No, as I simply haven't searched since (deviated to other matters). However, I'm still curious about the topic. So, please feel free to comment or update the answer, should you find relevant R packages.